# How do I provide a Uri like ms:appx:/// to Process class for starting a new process?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to start a process using Process.start(), however my .exe is embedded in my app and I gain access to it by using ms-appx:///. Process.filename expects a string while I can get a StorageFile by doing

```
StorageFile A = await await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new URi(ms-appx:////blahblah);
```

How do I pass this to Process.StorageInfo.filename ? As this expects a string

Comment: I don't think you can. With that command you're instructing the OS to start a new process, but the OS can not look inside of your app. But I'm no expert on this.

Comment: Is there a way the OS can look inside my app to find the path?

Comment: Well, I did some lookup and `GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync` returns a `StorageFile`. `StorageFile` has a `Path` property. Is that set for your call? If that is the case, you could use that for the `Process.Start()` call. Note: your application might not have permission to start a process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UWP Possible to run a process using StorageFile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56795759/uwp-possible-to-run-a-process-using-storagefile)

Comment: Any updates about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch your .exe file which is embedded inside your UWP project, I'd suggest you use the [FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher.launchfulltrustprocessforcurrentappasync?view=winrt-22000). This method could directly start the .exe file from your UWP app.

There are three steps that you needs to do:

1. Add the **Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP** as a reference in your UWP app.
2. Add the `windows.fullTrustProcess` extension inside the Manifest file of your app. You could refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-19041#remarks) as a sample and it contains all the details.
3. call the `LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync` method like this:

   ```
   await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
   ```

Comment: With these kinds of questions I'm always wondering if this is some script kiddie that's trying to make an app that start spyware on some remote computer xD. Luckily that's not so easy nor straightforward.